# Google Sheet App Script. Copy specific Column from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-4bK9BMSn-7NAKyvE-imvJaxT_MBVQrfHLtl8tmL5c/edit#gid=200808842)I'm doing something in Google Sheet. I want to transfer specific data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 using App Script. The problem is I can copy the data from specific column, but it wasn't aligned to the specific data. I want to align them but when I add data it will add at the bottom part of the column.

Here's the code. I try to modify.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Refresh Data', 'copyData')
      .addToUi();
}

function copyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BEDs_Main');
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BED 1 & 3');
  
  // Get the data range from the source sheet
  var sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  
  // Get the values from the source sheet
  var sourceValues = sourceDataRange.getValues();
  
  // Loop through the rows in the source sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    
    // Get the values from each column in the current row
    var column1Value = sourceValues[i][0];
    var column2Value = sourceValues[i][1];
    var column3Value = sourceValues[i][2];
    var column4Value = sourceValues[i][3];
    
    // Append the values to the target sheet
    targetSheet.appendRow([column1Value, column2Value, column3Value, column4Value]);
  }
}
```

[The problem I want to fix or modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhVH4.png)

I try to get the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and it will align not in the bottom. I'm expecting that it will align together.

[Google Sheet Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-4bK9BMSn-7NAKyvE-imvJaxT_MBVQrfHLtl8tmL5c/edit#gid=200808842)

Comment: Please provide an example of the data in the source sheet and an example of the expected outcome.

Comment: I edited the question. I added the the sample link of google sheet

Comment: Please put everything needed to answer the question in the question.  I will not follow links to your spreadsheet

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you'll likely need some reference columns in both sheets like ID or Email to align the values. Just yesterday I wrote a short blog about it  https://kcl.hashnode.dev/how-to-easily-copy-a-column-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-google-sheets